# Android - Cursor Loader - Dynamically Modify Result

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, line-breaks

I have a database for my app but some of the entries had line breaks in them so I had to replace "\n" with "$$" when I accept the user entry to keep the insert statement valid. I need to show the line break when I return the data to the user.

In short, I need to accept input that include line breaks, store it to db, then display back to user properly with line breaks.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Here is my code to insert into the database-

```
    //first replace \n (i used StringUtils b/c i found it to be slightly faster)
    category =  StringUtils.replace(category, "\n", "");
    subCategory = StringUtils.replace(subCategory,"\n", "");
    brand =     StringUtils.replace(brand,"\n", "");
    name =      StringUtils.replace(name,"\n", "");
    notes =     StringUtils.replace(notes,"\n", "$$");

    initialValues.put(KEY_CATEGORY, category);
    initialValues.put(KEY_SUB_CATEGORY, subCategory);
    initialValues.put(KEY_BRAND, brand);
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_NOTES, notes);

    db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
```

Comment: Show us your code. If you're using Android's SQLiteDatabase object, with the query, update, insert methods, you can put a string containing line-breaks in the parameters, and they'll come back out just fine, no conversion needed.

Answer (score 0):

As 323go says, you can use strings containing line breaks if you use a parameterised insert query. I've no direct experience of doing so myself, but I don't doubt he is correct. However it sounds like you already have data in your database formatted with $$ for a line break.

The ASCII hex value for a line break is 0A and if you select x'0A' in SQLite, a line feed should result. You can therefore try replacing instances of $$ with x'0A' when you select. For example you would replace this statement:

```
SELECT name FROM table
```

...with:

```
SELECT REPLACE(name, '$$', x'0A') AS name FROM table
```